# Detect usb port android dongle

Tags: android, usb

I am working on a Android project. I need a small help in that. Can some one guide me how do i check if the USB port is enabled or not in the Android device.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797792/how-to-check-if-usb-connected-mode-is-enabled-on-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use BroadCastReceiver with following actions,

```
<receiver android:name=".DetactUSB">
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.UMS_DISCONNECTED" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In the BroadcastReceiver you can code like below to check,

```
public class DetactUSB extends BroadcastReceiver
{ 
    private static final String TAG = "DetactUSB";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase( "android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED"))
        {
                TextView textView = new TextView(context);
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
                textView.setText("USB connected……….");
                Toast toastView = new Toast(context);
                toastView.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toastView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);
                toastView.setView(textView);
                toastView.show();
                Log.i(TAG,"USB connected..");
        }
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase( "android.intent.action.UMS_DISCONNECTED"))
        {
                TextView textView = new TextView(context);
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
                textView.setText("USB Disconnected……….");
                Toast toastView = new Toast(context);
                toastView.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toastView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);
                toastView.setView(textView);
                toastView.show();
        }
    } 
}
```