# Detecting if phone is plugged into pc

Tags: java, android

I want to detect if a phone is plugged into a pc or will be unplugged...so in my manifest i have:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="de.name.usbtest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        >
    </service>
</application>
```

My Service Class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    USBBroadcast usbTrigger = null;
    // create new USBTrigger()() and register for ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED broadcasts
    usbTrigger = new USBBroadcast();
    registerReceiver(usbTrigger, new IntentFilter(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED));
}
```

My Broadcastreceiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

and my Main Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);

    startService(serviceIntent);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

But i never see the Toast, when i plug in my phone...Anyone knows why?!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to `show()` the `Toast`

```
Toast.makeText(ctx, "Received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Nah, i just forgot to paste it here...In Code i have it with "show()"

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED"/>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_UMS_DISCONNECTED"/>
```

as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8797858/1952459).

Comment: USB mass storage is long deprecated